# Why do I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TAP'" when TAP is installed?

Tags: python

I am trying to use Rx to validate a YAML document against a schema, but python can't find the TAP module even though I've just installed it and I can see it's right there:

```
[:~/git/Rx/python] [my-venv] master* ± python3 rx-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atsaloli/git/Rx/python/rx-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TAP.Simple import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TAP'
[:~/git/Rx/python] [my-venv] master* 1 ± pip3 freeze | grep -i tap
tap==0.2
tap.py==3.1
[:~/git/Rx/python] [my-venv] master* ± ls /home/atsaloli/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tap/
adapter.py    formatter.py  line.py    __main__.py  parser.py    rules.py   tests
directive.py  __init__.py   loader.py  main.py      __pycache__  runner.py  tracker.py
[:~/git/Rx/python] [my-venv] master* ±
```

Rx is https://rjbs.manxome.org/rx/index.html

Similar questions (no accepted answer):

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script' but script actually exist and directory precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956686/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-script-but-script-actually-exist-and-dire)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' even when module is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291357/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysql-even-when-module-is-installed)
- [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named?rq=1)

P.S. I did install `tap`:

```
[:~/git/learn_python/yaml-validator] [my-venv] 1 $ pip install tap
Requirement already satisfied: tap in /home/atsaloli/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mc_bin_client in /home/atsaloli/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from tap) (1.0.1)
[:~/git/learn_python/yaml-validator] [my-venv] $
```

Comment: You did `pip install tap`?

Comment: In the meantime, I am able to use "schema" module instead (to validate my YAML).  I would still like to understand why this happened.